# How check internet on client pc and give him weather report in asp.net with C#?

Tags: asp.net

I have a web site on IIS on windows xp. I am showing live weather report on my LAN users but some of my LAN users don't have access to internet but they can access my website on LAN.

How can I check internet not working on client PC and show him message or how I should manage weather report that even LAN user can access it?

Comment: How about internet connection sharing: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306126

Comment: Why do you need to check the clients have internet access or not - if they are all LAN connected just serve it directloy from the web server via the intranet - as long as the web server can get to the internet or access whatever files are involved that are downloaded by another machine that the web server can read.

Comment: @rene: Please don't send IIS / ASP.NET / C# questions to Super User, thank you.

Comment: @TomWijsman I doubt it is an asp.net problem. But I'll ask the OP the next time. I had no reaction on my comment from the OP though....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ASP.NET Client Callback,we can check the internet connectivity. From the client side try to download a simple webpage. If the page is downloaded successfully then user is connected to the internet else he is not connected. Your dummy page (The page that you are going to download) should be very small to get good performance.

check here for sample code

http://highoncoding.com/Articles/316_Find_User_s_Internet_Connectivity_Using_ASP_NET_2_0_Client_Callback.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check internet access via Javascript, you cannot do it from server side, and you may not want to check for internet access per se, but for access to the website you are getting the weather report from (if this site is blocked by a firewall rule, then you cannot display the result).

You could do it by [pinging the website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282151/is-it-possible-to-ping-a-server-from-javascript), and then use the result of that Javascript ping to display one of two divs - weather forecast or "Sorry, no access to weather service available for you."