# How to detect if the server shutdown?

Tags: javascript, shutdown

How to detect if the server shut down during the client has visited a page with javascript?

A request with a forever keep-alive header could do it, but the problem is that fires even when the user navigates away from the page.

Comment: because it's not there any more?.....  Why would a server shutdown? Surely that's a rare event, right? That's why we have clusters, UPS's and redundant drives...

Comment: You may do an ajax request and see if it fails.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282151/is-it-possible-to-ping-a-server-from-javascript

Comment: I guess that by "server is down" you actually mean "server is not responsive". Making any fake AJAX call with timeout will do.

Comment: you can wait X seconds before considering the server as down. This way if the user is leaving the page, the timeout will prevent him from viewing the "server is down" message.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat If you are a developer it's definetly not rare :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is a bit of a naive approach, but you could count the number of response headers when an ajax call fails. With jQuery, for instance, you could do this:

```
$.ajax( {
    'url': urlToTheServer,
    'success': function()
    {
        // server is up
    },
    'error': function( $xhr )
    {
        if( $xhr.getAllResponseHeaders().length < 1 )
        {
            // fair probability server is down
        }
    }
} );
```

The way I tested this, on my development box, is wrap the above in a `setTimeout()` call (with say, a 10 sec. timeout). Load the page. Shutdown server. And then wait for the timeout to expire and do the ajax request.

PS.: `$xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()` returns a newline delimited string of headers, not an array or object of headers. I overlooked this at first, however, this doesn't change the outcome of the script. If the string length of `$xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()` is less than `1`, no response headers were present.

Comment: Do you mean if the server fails there are no headers?

Comment: Yes, I just tested this with shutting down my Apache server. It works the way I expected.

Comment: This works if I send the request while the server is down. And this is what I actually asked in my question. So I accept your answer. However I just realized that what I'm really looking for is checking if a forever keep-alive ajax request fails because of a server shutdown or by user abort(ex: navigating away), but I'm making a new question out of this.

Comment: @Adam Ah, I see. My apologies for not interpreting your question to its full extent. Good luck with the other question. To be honest: I'm not even sure I fully understand what a "forever keep-alive ajax request" actually means, so I'll be following your next question with interest.

Comment: here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883990/check-request-fail-reason-in-javascript