# how to know a machine is reachable from browser/js

Tags: javascript, web-applications, browser, cross-browser

This might look weird, to ask such a question besides knowing browsers/js limitations. But still I want know if anybody has any hints.

I have a web application running, on a page I accept a ip address from user, ip address of user's device, which is ideally a network resource. This ip is suppose to be reachable from users' desk.

Having accepted that ip address, I still want to check from browser, using some js, whether it is really reachable.

Any idea.

Note: Am already regexing it to check whether is seems an intranet resource or not.

Comment: how about sending the IP back to your server, getting your server to ping it and returning the result?

Comment: its not an internet resource reachable from anywhere, its a user's local intranet resource, reachable from user's desk only

Comment: So you're trying to generate a ping from the user's computer via javascript? If so try looking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282151/is-it-possible-to-ping-a-server-from-javascript)

Comment: Thanks @kevmc, `img.onerror, img.src` worked out, but dont know how all other browsers will act up