# Is it possible to use javascript to check if a webserver is up?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a webapp that will list the up/down status of several remote servers on a network, and can't seem to find any sort of functionality that would enable me to query the status of these servers without ajax. Does such a functionality exist, or should I be looking into other languages for this? If the latter case is true, what should I use?

Comment: What's wrong with using AJAX?

Comment: Check [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282151/is-it-possible-to-ping-a-server-from-javascript) it was previously answered.

Comment: @YotamOmer I saw that, but I wasn't certain exactly how it worked. I'm attempting to run a function based on the result of the "ping", and so I need something that returns true or false. If what you linked does that, can you explain it a little?

Comment: Regarding not using ajax - I tried using xmlhttprequests, but from my understanding, using them across domains doesn't work. This was further backed up by me recieving the error: `Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Comment: yeah, then the image trick proposed on @YotamOmer's link should do the trick