# jQuery : check if websites online status using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a database of website addresses, and need some kind of "loop" to check this websites online status using jQuery AJAX.

before

```
URLs                        | status
----------------------------|--------
http://www.google.com       |
http://www.yahoo.com        |
http://www.lycos.com        |
http://www.blablabla.com    |

[btn_CheckOnlineStatus]
```

after i push `[btn_CheckOnlineStatus]`

```
URLs                        | status
----------------------------|--------
http://www.google.com       | online
http://www.yahoo.com        | offline
http://www.lycos.com        | online
http://www.blablabla.com    | online

[btn_CheckOnlineStatus]
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by online status?

Comment: Do you have a particular problem with that? Please post your code and explain what the issues you have with it.

Comment: @armen That's nice. What would you like me to do about this?

Comment: Doing it with ajax you will have a Same Origin Policy problem. You'll have to proxy each request through some server side script on the same domain.

Comment: with online status i mean if you write the given address, the response will be 500 (i think), and not 404 ( `Page Cannot Be Found` ), or no `Server not found`. in other words site is up and running.

Comment: @armen Is this question is kind about HTTP request?

Comment: jQuery is something very new to me, and i think the task is simple. all i need is a client side script that can check if given address has a normal response or not, that is if i type www.google.com in my browser, i'll see google website in front of me, and if i type xyz.qwerqwer.jkl my browser will complain about `server not found`! i need this "check" be done by a script with a status message.

Comment: That has 0 to do with jQuery and all to do with how the browser will allow javascript access to foreign sites. Try the script in the link to the other question. If it works for you, you are done. Alternatively have a server process do the work and reprot to javaScript

Answer (score 3):

You need to ping that sites, I only know to ping site through java.

This question is related to you:

[Is it possible to ping a server from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282151/is-it-possible-to-ping-a-server-from-javascript)

Comment: this is a good post, and partially covers my question, but even the accepted answer does not function correctly.