# Need a script to keep web page from dropping connection

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, keep-alive

Im looking for a script that will do something like a ping in the background while connected to a web app. Keep alive? I've looked into greasemonkey which uses javascript and have considered  a python script. Im a babe, I know very little Python and hardly nothing about javascript. Can someone educate me? I need the script to keep a security checkin app from timing out and dropping connection to the host. The script will be a temporary fix because the real issue is network related.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to ping a server from Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282151/is-it-possible-to-ping-a-server-from-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

It kinda depends on the app you're trying to stay connected to, but if you go with javascript, you can set up a [timeInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) and have it make an [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call to one of the web app's exposed api urls. The url and parameters of the ajax call really depend on the web app you're trying to stay connected to.

```
setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "[web_app_uri]/check_in_method",
        data: JSON.stringify(parameters_for_method)
    });
}, 1000 * 60);
```