# How to calculate latency between server and client using c#.net?

Tags: c#

I am a beginner at C#.net. So, I want to write a program to find the network latency between Server and Client machines.

Comment: Well that's very nice of you. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way for you to know the latency between the server and the client is to use Javascript in the client page. Because when you generate you C# code it doesn't know anything about the client.

Use this solution : [Is it possible to ping a server from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282151/is-it-possible-to-ping-a-server-from-javascript)