# Mobile HTML 5: Detect internet connection availability

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, websocket, connection

Just that, is there a way to detect if the internet connection is available on a mobile device?.  Can I do some kind of ping to server using websockets? Will websockets help me with that?

I'm kinda desperate, because I thought websockets had a ping function on the client-side box, but not I try to find something about that, and there's nothing like that, besides websockets seem only to respond to connections and data transmission events.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to ping a server, as you already considered. 
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282151/is-it-possible-to-ping-a-server-from-javascript) contains a working example which uses the native Image object to do this.

I hope this helps.