# Cross domain request initiating from server side

Tags: cors

I am attempting to send a POST from the server side of my application to a CDN hosted by Amazon. I believe I may be running into a CORS issue. My question is this: I understand that CORS issues exist when posting from a client side application such as a web browser, but do they also exist when posting from the server side to another domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same origin policy does not apply to server initiated requests, only from browser-based requests.  So, CORS is not a factor here.

Comment: is there a reason for that though? why is it that server-side requests are treated differently than browser requests?

Comment: Cross-origin server side requests have never been restricted by the same origin policy.  Browser-based requests have.  CORS lifts that restriction a bit, but requires you follow a few rules (outlined in the CORS spec).

Comment: I have discussed this a bit in a past answer.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22108815/486979