# Ajax No Access-Control-Allow-Origin using type 'HEAD'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I ran into this problem when using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381663/how-to-check-if-image-exists-with-given-url/3381694#3381694) to check if the image is valid.

However I get a

> No Access-Control-Allow-Origin error

, and I have no access to the image server.

Any help will be appreciate!

Comment: perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107694/why-does-a-cross-origin-head-request-need-a-preflight-check) will enlighten you ... reading the question again ... does the server allow cross origin requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies within JS policy not to allow cross-origin (or to put it simple - cross-domain) requests to prevent intrusions etc. If the server does not allow cross-origin requests (using specific headers in communication), you won't be able to get your image even if it exists.

[This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) and [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) should enlighten you a bit.