# Table entry works fine in development but not in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a product page that when you buy the product, it will redirect to a purchase page (the receipt and download page).

**Everything works fine in development** on my local computer but when a purchase goes through in production on the remote server it charges the customer (using **Stripe**) but doesn't create an entry in the `purchase` table - which doesn't allow the customer to download their product. I checked the "purchases" table in `psql` on the remote server and it doesn't have any rows/entries.

It is supposed to send an email as well - linking to the purchase page, which only works in development as well.

I am using **PostgreSQL** on both my local computer and the remote server.

**charges controller**:

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    set_meta_tags noindex: true
  end

  def create
    pack = Pack.find(params[:product_id])

    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :email => params[:stripeEmail],
      :source  => params[:stripeToken],
    )

    # Amount in cents
    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :customer    => customer.id,
      :amount      => pack.price_in_cents,
      :description => 'Product Purchase',
      :currency    => 'usd',
    )

    purchase = Purchase.create(
      email: params[:stripeEmail],
      card: params[:stripeToken],
      amount: pack.price_in_cents,
      description: charge.description,
      currency: charge.currency,
      customer_id: customer.id,
      product_id: pack.id,
      uuid: SecureRandom.uuid,
    )

    redirect_to purchase

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to new_charge_path
  end

end
```

**purchases_controller**:

```
class PurchasesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @title = 'Purchase Receipt';
    @purchase = Purchase.find_by_uuid(params[:id])
    @pack = Pack.find(@purchase.product_id)
    set_meta_tags noindex: true
  end

end
```

**Purchase model**:

```
class Purchase < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :download_token
  after_create :email_purchaser

  def to_param
    uuid
  end

  def email_purchaser
    PurchaseMailer.purchase_receipt(self).deliver
  end

  def Purchase.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def create_download
    self.download_token = Purchase.email.new_token
    update_attribute(:download, Purchase.email(download_token))
    update_attribute(:download_sent_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

end
```

**purchase_mailer:**

```
class PurchaseMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  layout 'purchase_mailer'
  default from: "First Last <myemail@gmail.com>"

  def purchase_receipt purchase
    @purchase = purchase
    mail to: purchase.email, subject: "Thank you for your purchase. Here's your download link, enjoy!"
  end

end
```

**Link to purchase.show view in the sent email:**

`<%= link_to "DOWNLOAD", purchase_url(@purchase), target: "_blank" %>`

Here are the server logs:

```
I, [2019-01-11T22:04:21.404919 #17222]  INFO -- : [14c2eed0-3aae-4ab6-8142-9aa9744819af] Started HEAD "/https://mywebsite.com/" for XX.XXX.XXX.XXX at 2019-01-11 22:04:21 +0000
F, [2019-01-11T22:04:21.405538 #17222] FATAL -- : [14c2eed0-3aae-4ab6-8142-9aa9744819af]
F, [2019-01-11T22:04:21.405585 #17222] FATAL -- : [14c2eed0-3aae-4ab6-8142-9aa9744819af] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [HEAD] "/https:/mywebsite.com"):
F, [2019-01-11T22:04:21.405611 #17222] FATAL -- : [14c2eed0-3aae-4ab6-8142-9aa9744819af]
F, [2019-01-11T22:04:21.405648 #17222] FATAL -- : [14c2eed0-3aae-4ab6-8142-9aa9744819af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:63:in `call'
[14c2eed0-3aae-4ab6-8142-9aa9744819af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
[14c2eed0-3aae-4ab6-8142-9aa9744819af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
[14c2eed0-3aae-4ab6-8142-9aa9744819af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
[14c2eed0-3aae-4ab6-8142-9aa9744819af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
[14c2eed0-3aae-4ab6-8142-9aa9744819af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
[14c2eed0-3aae-4ab6-8142-9aa9744819af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
[14c2eed0-3aae-4ab6-8142-9aa9744819af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
[14c2eed0-3aae-4ab6-8142-9aa9744819af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
[14c2eed0-3aae-4ab6-8142-9aa9744819af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
[14c2eed0-3aae-4ab6-8142-9aa9744819af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
[14c2eed0-3aae-4ab6-8142-9aa9744819af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
[14c2eed0-3aae-4ab6-8142-9aa9744819af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
[14c2eed0-3aae-4ab6-8142-9aa9744819af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
[14c2eed0-3aae-4ab6-8142-9aa9744819af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
[14c2eed0-3aae-4ab6-8142-9aa9744819af] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
[14c2eed0-3aae-4ab6-8142-9aa9744819af] /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:97:in `process_request'
[14c2eed0-3aae-4ab6-8142-9aa9744819af] /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:157:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
[14c2eed0-3aae-4ab6-8142-9aa9744819af] /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:110:in `main_loop'
[14c2eed0-3aae-4ab6-8142-9aa9744819af] /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:415:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
[14c2eed0-3aae-4ab6-8142-9aa9744819af] /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:113:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'
```

Here is the server log after adding `!` to `purchase = Purchase.create!(` in the charges controller:

```
F, [2019-01-15T21:21:12.869293 #24540] FATAL -- : [932479d4-c710-4ac6-9159-8c3fa5299adc] ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'uuid' for Purchase.):
```

Here is my routes.rb File:

```
  resources :charges
  resources :purchases, only: [:show]
```

I have removed `get 'purchase' => 'purchases#show', as: 'purchase'` from `routes.rb` as it was breaking my code.

It was making the URL do this: `https://mywebsite.com/purchase.uuid`

Instead of this: `https://mywebsite.com/purchase/uuid`

Here is my config/environments/production.rb file:

```
Rails.application.configure do
config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  host = 'transverseaudio.com'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'transverseaudio.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

After running `rails routes`:

```
            charges GET    /charges(.:format)                                charges#index
                    POST   /charges(.:format)                                charges#create
         new_charge GET    /charges/new(.:format)                            charges#new
        edit_charge GET    /charges/:id/edit(.:format)                       charges#edit
             charge GET    /charges/:id(.:format)                            charges#show
                    PATCH  /charges/:id(.:format)                            charges#update
                    PUT    /charges/:id(.:format)                            charges#update
                    DELETE /charges/:id(.:format)                            charges#destroy
           purchase GET    /purchases/:id(.:format)                          purchases#show
```

Comment: After update, what is your problem?

Comment: can you share the output of your rails routes task?

Comment: On your project folder run: "rails routes" if is rails 5 or "rake routes"  for older versions

Comment: run `rake routes | grep purchase`

Comment: It could be helpful to see your production settings (without sensitive data) in config/environments/production.rb

Comment: Can you repeat the process a get the logs again to see if there is something else?

Comment: Maybe you have not run migrations in productions and the uuid column is not present in purchases table?

Comment: @MatFiz wow, that must be it. I just checked my table on the server via `psql` and there is no uuid column.

Comment: I am glad I could help. I will provide it as an answer below, pls accept ;)

Comment: Have you resetarted the rails server after applying the migration? The error `F, [2019-01-15T21:21:12.869293 #24540] FATAL -- : [932479d4-c710-4ac6-9159-8c3fa5299adc] ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'uuid' for Purchase.):` comes now from the rails model.

Comment: @MatFiz Sorry, I meant I found the error I mentioned about the uuid by using the `!` and yes I did and it worked, please update your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to wrap the `ChargesController.create` in a transaction. In case of some (eg. validation) error in `Purchase.create`, you end up in some partial data created in db + real transaction in Stripe. Also, it would be a good improvement to check if the `purchase` has been actually created:

```
if purchase
  redirect_to purchase
else 
  render :new, error: purchase.errors
end
```

Then in production GUI you will clearly see what is the problem.

Also, in your logs `F, [2019-01-15T21:21:12.869293 #24540] FATAL -- : [932479d4-c710-4ac6-9159-8c3fa5299adc] ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'uuid' for Purchase.):`, which might mean your migrations were not applied in prod and you're simply missing uuid column in `Purchase`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are getting a HEAD request. Your routes dont seem to be able to handle this. Don't worry this is kind of normal.

This is a CORS preflight check happening. Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

And

[Why does a cross-origin HEAD request need a preflight check?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107694/why-does-a-cross-origin-head-request-need-a-preflight-check)

For rails Try Rack Cors:
https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors this may help.

Essentially Rack CORS will allow your app to respond to the preflight checks appropriately.