# Check cross domain server availability from client's machine (with JSONP, pinging etc.)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I need to check whether a cross-domain server is available or not. Choices are:
- sending ping
- getting a HEAD request
- making own server as proxy server and pass cross-domain server data in arguments
- making a JSONP request

- I want to do this in client side (I can always reach cross-domain server from my server).
- I need to know client's state. So javascript is mandatory.
- I don't want to use own server as proxy, because this can cause security problems and I can't know client's state.
- I tried JSONP below, but it is also OK to have a ping solution or any other solution that you can recommend.
- I don't have any privilege in cross-domain server. I can only make restful requests from server with api key.
- I prefer asynced, jquery based solutions. But it is ok to use pure javascript.
- The only thing I need is to check whether server is available or not. It would be better if I can know the response time from server. I don't need other data about server.

My fiddle is like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/HRrLc/1/).

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://twitter.com",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("success");
        //console.log("data2:"+data);
        //console.log("data:"+JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function (r, s, e) {
        console.log("error status: " + r.statusText + ", " + r.status);
        console.log("error r: " + r);
        console.log("error e: " + e);
    }
});
```

When I try this code I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < " error in first line of the response data. So consequent javascript codes doesn't work.

How can I check this availability ?

Comment: Is is fair to say if a connection is made the server is available or are you looking for a specific value from ajax call?

@patric-evans - thanks, I clicked the wrong button in haste.

Comment: The only thing I need is to check whether server is available or not, in client's machine. (I can reach from my server)

Comment: Do you have control of the remote server? A JSONP call needs a script at the other end that will wrap the JSON data in a callback function, suitable to be embedded in a `<script>` tag. You'll not get an error back from a JSONP call, but the success callback will never fire, so you'll need to set up a timeout that decides the server isn't available after a certain length of time.

Comment: @iain_simpson Thank you. I edited question. I don't have control on remote server. I can only make restful requests.

Comment: Server-side call is the way to go then, I'm afraid. You'll not be able to query Twitter directly from the browser - you need a proxy script.

Comment: Twitter's Javascript API is able to query the REST API because its script is loaded from that domain.

Comment: [You cannot send an actual PING from js](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4282151/1048572)