# how to ping to any website for status from frontend?

Tags: javascript, http, response

I have an input field in which i am asking user to enter the web URL. Now from frontend itself i want to check the  HTTP status codes of the URL entered.

Is it possible using jquery or javascript ? 
Any help is appreciated ;)

**HOW MY QUESTION IS DIFFERENT ?**

I wants to get status code from URL, not a ping from IP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282151/is-it-possible-to-ping-a-server-from-javascript

Comment: @Krishnakant I think it's not a duplicate, since he wants to get status code from URL, not a ping from IP

Answer (score 1):

For pages which allow cross-site scripting (XSS) (e.g. allow-control-allow-origin: * on the server side) you can do it with jQuery easily:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'https://www.example.com',
    type:'GET'})
    .always(function (jqXHR) {
                console.log(jqXHR.status);
});
```

But most pages will prevent XSS for good reasons!

Comment: Isn't this just a normal get?  This would result in actually fetching the contents of the page, not just pinging the response code.