# Chrome extension to check ping on cmd line

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Basically its a chrome extension that will check your ping. What we are trying to have happen is for the extension to open up cmd and issue the ping command to a google sever.

Comment: What's the problem you're having with it so far? Highly descriptive questions get the best answers!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour, have a look around, and read through [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular about [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in this site. Make an effort to solve the problem. If you run into a specific issue doing so, post a question with your attempt (including all the relevant code), saying what isn't working, and explaining your research so far.

Comment: the value of such an extension is dubious, good luck in writing it, come back and ask when you have a specific issue with code you have written

Answer (score 2):

I don't think extensions get that level of access to the system, as that would be insecure. Not to mention the absence of "cmd" under *nix and MacOS.

If you are looking for a JavaScript solution, you can try this:

[Is it possible to ping a server from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282151/is-it-possible-to-ping-a-server-from-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You could replicate the behavior of ping in the chrome native client (NaCL) sandbox, by sending [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) packets over raw sockets, using the [nacl_io](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/coding/nacl_io) library.