# Is there a way to access a random webpage with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make a button that takes you to a random website when clicked and I was wondering if there is any way of accessing web servers or something like that to randomly go to a website instead of making a huge array with dozens of websites like this:

```
var array = ['Lots','of','websites','here']
button.click(array[random])
```

Comment: Yes. Simply loop through all of the different letters of the alphabet, and allow for attempts for combinations between 4 and 20 characters in length. Then append `.com`, and redirect. However, there's no way of knowing whether you'll end up on a **valid** website or not without building them into an array, or piggybacking off of someone like Google.

Comment: Why don't you just redirect them to Google's "Feeling lucky?" page?

Comment: You could ping the random URL you generate and if you get a response it's most likely a valid website, you'd need to make it slightly less than random for this to not take an eternity though.

Comment: Just pick from the master list: https://www.whoisxmlapi.com/all-registered-domains.php

Comment: @ObsidianAge That's way too complicated for a very simple premise,but very interesting.I'll think about something I can use this technique in.

Comment: var website = "http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25";

Comment: @aaronw How do you ping a website from Javascript?

Comment: You can't really 'ping' a website from Javascript you would have to ping it on your server and do an ajax call to your server to get the result of that ping. There is a few ways to kind of trick javascript into letting you know if a website exists although some of these are apparently deprecated. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282151/is-it-possible-to-ping-a-server-from-javascript) question has some examples.