# Stop Ping After Trying 10 Times

Tags: javascript

I'm looked this question: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282151/is-it-possible-to-ping-a-server-from-javascript#comment76879738_11941783) to ping via **JavaScript** from the web, page. 

 in this Example: jsfiddle.net/Seabiscuit/u7nogfce/6/ I want to stop trying ping after 10 times retries. by default that example can give you many many trying to ping call back till responded:
[image]

this is @seebiscuit JS code:

```
const TIMEOUT = 1500;let c = 0;function ping(ip, callback) {

if (!this.inUse) {
    this.status = 'unchecked';
    this.inUse = true;
    this.callback = callback;
    this.ip = ip;
    var _that = this;
    this.img = new Image();
    this.img.onload = function (e) {
        _that.inUse = false;
        _that.callback('responded', e);

    };
    this.img.onerror = function (e) {
        if (_that.inUse) {
            _that.inUse = false;
            _that.callback('responded', e);
        }

    };
    this.start = new Date().getTime();
    this.img.src = "http://" + ip;
    this.timer = setTimeout(function () {
        if (_that.inUse) {
            _that.inUse = false;
            _that.callback('timeout');
        }
    }, TIMEOUT);
}}var PingModel = function (servers) {
var self = this;
var myServers = [];
ko.utils.arrayForEach(servers, function (location) {
    myServers.push({
        name: location,
        status: ko.observable('unchecked'),
        retry:  ko.observable(0)
    });
});
self.servers = ko.observableArray(myServers);
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.servers(), function (s) {
    s.status('checking');
    alertWhenLive(s, function (status, e) {console.log(s.name,'callback retries', s.retry)
        s.status(status);debugger;
        s.retry(s.retry() + 1);
    }, function (name) { alert(name + " is back online!") });

    function alertWhenLive (server, callback, alertCallback) {

      pingUntilSuccess();

      function pingUntilSuccess (status, e) {
        if (status) callback(status, e);
        console.log(server.name, 'status')
                    if (status && status !== 'timeout') {debugger;
            if (server.retry() > 1) alertCallback(server.name);

          return;
        }

        new ping(server.name, pingUntilSuccess);
        }
    }
});};var komodel = new PingModel(['localhost',
'www.google.com:81',
'ws-bdimperio8.payformance.net',
'ws-bdimperio8.payformance.com',
'ws-bdimperio8.payspan.com',
'ws-bdimperio8/favicon.ico',
'127.0.0.1', 
'unknown'
]);
```

ko.applyBindings(komodel);

Comment: You should include your current javascript code inside the post

Comment: yes bro, i included, the code in here:  http://jsfiddle.net/Seabiscuit/u7nogfce/6/