# designate an errorpage.html for a JS document.getElementById('link_id').value + '.html'; if value not found in directory?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a function for a popup search function, which, when a word is typed, and enter is pressed (the handleKeyPress(e) function, it automatically goes to say, dogs.html (its a kids language learning app). However say they type 'dogg' and not 'dog', Iw ould like it to go to a designated error page. I cannot code at all and have only manipulated other people's scripts. for example, the directory
would have a list of animals.html, i.e. dog.html, cat.html, etc. but if a word is typed that is not in this directory

(there should be a search function to see if *.html is there or not, then go to error page if its not there. But I can't do this. I have no training. Can anyone help me with this?  I hope I don't get thrown off this forum again, you really shouldn't be so harsh on idiots...!)
i.e. what I need is : if .value+'.html' not in dir;
 goto errorpage.html

Here's "my" code to load whatever word's page that's typed in:

```
function goTo()
{
    location.href = document.getElementById('link_id').value + '.html';
    /*window.location.replace("spellcheck.html");*/
}  

function handleKeyPress(e){
     var key=e.keyCode || e.which;
           if (key==13){
           goTo(); 
        /*window.location.replace("spellcheck.html");   */
     }
}
```

Comment: I believe error pages are handled by the server, not something that's really done with JavaScript. You could try to ping the web page to see if it exists and then intelligently redirect (this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282151/is-it-possible-to-ping-a-server-from-javascript ) but you'll have to make the user wait for a suitable amount of time to determine if the page does/does not exist.  From the server it should be much quicker and cleaner.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem for me is I'm not using any kind of server I'm just, I suppose too inexperienced - its an html/css/javascript site that I'm porting with the Apache Cordova Extension in Visual Studio... I suppose it can't be done without a server... or a search for the input.html in the current dir, and IF not found, as mentioned a redirect to a custom error page. that would omit the need for a server, but I can do neither...  That specific directory though does not even have 140 .html files in it.

Comment: If your files are not dynamic (under your control) you could make an array/list of all the files that you know to exist and check against that

Comment: But this will only help you from this specific access point. If someone tried to navigate to dogg.html on their own then it has to be the server to trigger a 404 page

Comment: ah Doug, thanks for that. I will have to figure out what an array list is and how to incorporate that, I'm a total n00b! Yes, they're static (not dynamic). I will try and look into that, otherwise I am removing the search function, although it might have been a useful as a dictionary (its a language learning app). In fact, it would have been a major aspect but, I just can't do this, I'm too inexperienced, so I'm excluding it if Ic annot manage the array list to be referred to. Thank you, though, I will attempt your suggestion!

Comment: and yes I am porting it to  an android .apk so they wouldn't be able to navigate, great advice Doug, you're a star! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to use an [XmlHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) to check if the file exists in the location specified or not and redirect to the error page if the file doesn't exist.  But this raises it's own set of problems.

Or, you could create a service on the server that could tell you the same.  Either way it's not super easy.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier, you can create an array that can hold all of the values for the pages you know to exist in your site.

(there's a decent amount of commented text in the code snippet for further details)

JavaScript arrays: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

JavaScript .indexOf() (in relation to arrays): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

A JavaScript array is a series of data that is common separated inside of square brackets.  Each element is automatically assigned an index value so that developers can quickly reference specific pieces.  However, it's important to know that arrays start their index number at 0...

So, in this example:

`const arrayName = ['element1', 'element2', 'page3', 'dog']`

- `'element1'` is at index `0` inside arrayName
- `'element2'` is at index `1` inside arrayName
- `'page3'` is at index `2` inside arrayName
- `'dog'` is at index `3` inside arrayName

You can use JavaScript array's `.indexOf()` to find these array index values.  If an element does not exist within an array then `.indexOf()` will return -1 (negative one).

`arrayName.indexOf( 'dog' )` === `3`

```js
// get the input element that's getting the text
const linkID  = document.getElementById('link_id');
// get the search button
const linkBtn = document.getElementById('link_btn');

// listen for when the keyup event (so when the user is
// typing, this will trigger when a key is released)
linkID.addEventListener('keyup', (e)=>{
  // get the keyCode to test for [ENTER]/13
  let key    = e.keyCode || e.which;
  // get the textBox element
  let target = e.target  || e.srcElement;
  // test if the [ENTER] key was hit
  if( key === 13 ){
    // if [ENTER] test the value 
    processPage( target.value );
  }
});

// Listen to the click event on the search button to 
// kick off the process workflow...
linkBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  processPage( linkID.value );
});

// Broke this out so that the processing of the text
// field can be done by [ENTER] or by clicking a 
// search button
function processPage( val ){
  // checkPage will return true/false if the text matches
  // a page in the array list
  if( checkPage( val ) ){
    // if the page does exist, then kick off the redirect
    goTo( val );
  }else{
    // display an error message
    alert( 'Sorry, the page you are looking for does not exist' );
    // reset the value of #link_id 
    linkID.value = '';
  }
}

// This function checks if the text value submitted matches
// one of the static pages saved to the array
function checkPage( val ){
  // pages[] is an array that holds all the pages you know
  // to exist
  const pages  = ['dog', 'cat', 'bunny'];
  
  // .indexOf() will return the array position of a search
  // query (in this case the value of val)
  // Arrays start at 0 so if the user searches "dog" the
  // .indexOf() will provide the answer 0.
  // If an element does not exist, .indexOf() returns -1
  // By assigning this as a condition: 
  //    "is the index of val from the array pages[] greater
  //     than or equal to 0?"
  // we create a condition that will return true/false
  return ( pages.indexOf( val ) >= 0 );
}

function goTo( val ){
  console.log( val + '.html' );
  // location.href = val + '.html';
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="link_id" /><button id="link_btn">search</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, Doug. It will while before I can get to implement this, also will switch it to console.log(  '#' +val ); as I will be using jquery mobile with a multipage setup so that pages are written as divs with '# id tags' but display as loaded pages......  I was planning on excluding the search function, but it is possible I may manage thanks to you! A bit worried about the touch events since it should first allow the user to type, I think then enter should be specified specifically to implement the search function... even on mobiles, is char 13?

Comment: and ah, that search to test the key code, that is the real McCoy - i was reading from the bottom up! Its beginning to make sense, though I wish I did computer science... :(