# How detect Internet connectivity on client machine

Tags: php, jquery

In web development, is it possible to perform a have Internet connection  on client device. I have intranet and it can access within our VPN. I need to publish intranet to the internet.

I am using PHP for server, HTML/jquery for client side.

Comment: Look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282151/is-it-possible-to-ping-a-server-from-javascript