# Client pinging another client

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I found an old piece of javascript code that led to the client pinging anohter client:  `<script>var shell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell'); shell.Run('cmd /C start \"Ping......`
I'm wonderg ther now, with activeX not really "liked" by modern IIS versions is there any way to achieve a similar effect?

Comment: ActiveX is an obsolete technology.

Comment: @Amy I know that is what I meant with "not really liked by modern IIS versions" :)   now I'm trying to find out if there is any way to simulate what was done with that code with more modern technologies

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4282151/1267304

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I saw that one. Although fro what I noticed it is used to "ping" a http server. Thus the client pinging its server. Not a client pinging another client.

Comment: There is no way to really ping another server, you can make http head requests. Probably would need to do it from your server.

Comment: @epascarello that means then that there is no 1:1 replacement for the old activex variant (would be what I wanted to know)