# HTML JavaScript Weak network detecting

Tags: javascript, html, css, ping, offline

I want to make a weak network detector. I have already made an offline and an online detector. Like this: And of course with some JavaScript.

```
<body onoffline="offlineDetect()" ononline="onlineDetect()">
```

So my question is that is there any way to check is the connecton is above than for example 400ms, and if the ping reaches the 400ms a warning message appear?

Comment: you can maybe ping a server like you do with onlineDetect, but timing the ms to get the ping response? Maybe look at the second answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282151/is-it-possible-to-ping-a-server-from-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <script>
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var status = document.getElementById("status");
  var log = document.getElementById("log");

  function updateOnlineStatus(event) {
    var condition = navigator.onLine ? "online" : "offline";

    status.className = condition;
    status.innerHTML = condition.toUpperCase();

    log.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "Event: " + event.type + "; Status: " + condition);
  }

  window.addEventListener('online',  updateOnlineStatus);
  window.addEventListener('offline', updateOnlineStatus);
});
</script>
<div id="status"></div>
<div id="log"></div>
<p>This is a test</p>
```