# How to check if a particular localhost is up?

Tags: javascript

I am using the application running on a localhost:1234, In its javascript code I only want to execute a code if another localhost:9898 is up and running.
How can i check that on javascript level?
PS- I have tried window.location but it only works related to the same window,
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use `fetch` to get a response from the other server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to ping a server from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282151/is-it-possible-to-ping-a-server-from-javascript)