# How to ping ip address from java script

Tags: javascript, ip, ping

I need to ping IP address from java script, I found answers about using node.js but if I want to do it without, only clear java script, is it possible? and if it is how do I do that?

Comment: It is not possible to make a browser send icmp with Javascript.

Comment: Also this is a double duplicate btw

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4282151/8997916

Comment: I think there is third party services that can do that for you but there is no way in javascript to do it.